# How wrap around the plot if the value exceeds the xlim in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a well log plot in which I've put `xlim` condition. Suppose if my value exceeds the `xlim` it won't show in the plot, but what I want is to wrap around and if value is greater than `xlim` max that value should be wrapped around. That is, it should show on the same y position but not coming out of `xlim` min.

[image: Plot that I've made using matplotlib].

My code:

```
_, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (5,20))
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax.plot(df.GR, df.DEPT, 'red')
ax2.plot(df.SP, df.DEPT, 'blue')
ax.set_xlim(0, 150)
ax2.set_xlim(50, 90)
ax.set_xlabel('GR')
ax2.set_xlabel('SP')
ax.grid()
ax.set_xticks([0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150])
_.legend(['GR', 'SP'], bbox_to_anchor=(0.85,0.78), fontsize = 15)
```

Desired plot:

[image: Desired plot that I don't know which programming language made it].

Look at the last thick grid between 3900 m to 3925 m where you'll see that when the value exceeded `xlim` max it wrapped around and came from the left side of the plot i.e., `xlim` min side.

Also, I want to copy the same legend showing style as in the desired plot.

Answer (score 0):

For the 'wrap', you'll have to add another axis and control its limits separately. For the legend, there's no elegant solution, but you can manually adjust all the aspects of the x-axis labelling. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make some fake data.
y = np.linspace(0, 1000)
x1 = np.sin(y / 100) + 1.1 + 0.5 * np.random.random(50)

# Make the plot.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 10))
ax_wrap = ax.twiny()
ax_wrap.axis('off')

# Plot x1 in blue.
ax.plot(x1, y)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1.5)
ax_wrap.plot(x1, y, '--')  # <-- This is the wrapped data.
ax_wrap.set_xlim(1.5, 3.0) # <-- Wrapped data's limits.

# Adjust the x-axis position and colour.
ax.set_xticks((0, 1.5))
ax.spines['top'].set_position(('outward', 10))
ax.spines['top'].set_color('C0')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5, 1.03)
ax.set_xlabel('GR', color='C0', size=20)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='C0', size=0)
```

This results in:

[image: Resulting output]

Plotting logs is a bit of a headache. You might want to take a look at the following libraries, which might help in some of your work:

- [`petropy`](https://github.com/toddheitmann/PetroPy) — I haven't used it but the plot on the GitHub page looks pretty sweet.
- [`welly`](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/welly) — does not solve this specific problem, but I just made [an issue](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/welly/issues/124) for it.